# How to upload a xml file in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Can someone help me with a video tutorial or simple steps of how to upload a xml file in elastic search ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the XML file(s) from a logstash instance to store it to an Elasticsearch instance with the following logstash config.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/your/xml/*.xml"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"     
    } 
} 
filter {
    xml {
          source => "message"
          target => "doc"
          store_xml => false
          xpath => [
            "/msg/@time", "time",
            "/msg/@time_norm", "time_norm"
          ]
        }
    }
output {   
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }   
    stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FSCrawler also supports reading XML files. See https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/local-fs.html#indexing-xml-docs

Disclaimer: I'm the author of FSCrawler